# Is a c++ struct with std::map's a good design to have a dynamic data object?

Tags: c++, dynamic, struct, software-design

The question boils down to: Is it good design to have a struct in c++, which contains some `std::map` like containers to dynamically add information/properties to some object?

The object (see code snippet below) in my case is a `FitResult` returned by various optimizers (optimizing a set of parameters of a model, to describe a given data set best).

The `FitResult` contains information like:

- set of parameters describing a data set best
- error information on these parameters
- information about the optimization process and convergence
- etc

In my opinion this `FitResult` object is only data and does not need any functionality. Hence I would keep it a struct, without functions. Since the information stored in the object (as I listed above) can vary depending on the optimizer you are using, I want to keep the content of the `FitResult` dynamic. And to have an easy way to access the information later I decided to use a key value like container. The keys of the map do not have to be `std::string`'s, I thinking of using class enums instead to avoid typo errors.

Do you think this a good choice or would you go a different path, like a base class?

```cpp
struct FitResult {
  // these properties are separate members, since they are always given
  ParameterList InitialParameters;
  ParameterList FinalParameters;

  double InitialEstimatorValue = 0.0;
  double FinalEstimatorValue = 0.0;
  double ElapsedTimeInSeconds = 0.0;

  /// optional properties
  std::map<std::string, double> DoubleProperties;
  std::map<std::string, int> IntProperties;
  std::map<std::string, ParameterList> ParameterListProperties;
  std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>> DoubleListProperties;
  std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<double>>>
      MatrixProperties;
}
```

Edit:

My question was not phrased really well. I should have mentioned that in my case I do not need to have this feature of dynamically adding properties to the `FitResult`. Merely the different `Optimizer` classes need different sets of properties to add to the `FitResult`. The properties vary for the different `Optimizers`, but stay fixed otherwise.
However instead of using inheritance to add more member fields to the `FitResult` class, I wanted to use this dynamic struct approach. Which of these two solutions would you recommend?

Comment: Do you want sorted properties? Do you want keys? It depends on the need. Perhaps std::set is better, std::vector is better, or a custom container is better.

Comment: What kind of containers I use is a different question imho. I chose a key value pair like container, because I need an easy an reliable way to store and access my properties and speed is completely irrelevant. Actually I'm using `std::unordered_map`, because I do not need sorted properties (I tried to simplify the problem). I just want to know if people see or use this concept often and if they like it, or rather recommend using other concepts like an abstract base class.

Comment: In C++17, for the map, you could use `map<string, any>` or `map<string, optional<double, int, ParameterList, vector<double>, vector<vector<double>>>`.  (I've omitted the `std::` for brevity.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd consider a `map` of `string` to `variant<things you need>` instead of a container for each supported value type, but basically yes that looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah I agree, the `variant` makes it even better (did not know about `variant`) :)

Comment: In the current implementation of this software, this problem is solved by having a base class, which is extended via inheritance (adding new members and functions) by the various optimizers. I think that design is not good, since there was a lot of code duplication and overhead and required type casting from the base class. And its also not very stable for future extensions. Do you have a comment/thought on that?

Comment: I can only really imagine what that looks like, but off the top of my head your analysis sounds right. I wouldn't worry about it too much either way though unless it's really starting to scale badly.

Comment: Hmm ok. We are currently discussing this internally in the project (https://github.com/ComPWA/ComPWA/pull/187), but we cannot seem to come to a conclusion. The negative point raised against my `struct` + `std::map` solution is, that it is not known at compile time what is inside the map. So that an access to the `std::map` member is not guaranteed to be safe. And there is no automatic documentation about the members (contents of the `std::map`).
To me the pros overweight the cons though. Anyways, thanks for your time

Comment: @steve It's a tough one. All the points raised (on either side) are valid. Though if hyper-performance is not necessary then the complaints against `map` seem perhaps a _little_ overzealous. It really depends completely on the use case (which I don't know enough about) as to which is "better" at any given time.